# Products values not sending to addProduct page using php ajax

Tags: php

I am creating simple ecmommerce webisite while I am going to add products to card I couldn’t send the values through ajex.i have tried to send  'frmProduct' values to 'addproduct.php' page.  While I checking using echo echo $product_name = $_POST['des']; ,echo   $price = $_POST['price'];
    echo  $qty= $_POST['qty'];  only 'qty'   Value  sent successfully other fields are not sent to 
 'addproduct.php' page

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'all_product.php' ,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    var price = data[i].price;
                        var image = data[i].image;
                        var description = data[i].description;

    $("#Products").append("<form class='form-horizontal' id='frmProduct'>" +

           "<div class='col-md-4'> " +
                                  "<div class='panel panel-info' id='Products'>" +
                                  "<div class='card-body'>" +
                                  "<div class='panel-heading' id='des' "  +  "<h4> "  +  description + "</h4> " +
                                   "<p class='panel-body' id='price'>"+  "<h3> "  +  price + "</h3> "  +
                                    "<p class='panel-body'> " +
                                    "<img class='card-img-top' style='width:150px' height='150px' id='theImg' src='images/"  + image  + "' /> </p>" +
                                      "<input type='text' name='qty' id='qty'>" +
                                      "</br></br>" +
                                    " <Button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='addProduct()' >View More</a> " +

            "</div> " +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            " </div>" +
            "</form>");


        }
    },
```

$.ajax({

```
type : 'POST',
data : $("#'frmProduct'").serialize(),
url : 'addproduct.php',
dataType : 'JSON',
success : function(data){
```

}

addproduct.php page

```
<?php
include("db.php");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo   $product_name = $_POST['des'];
    echo   $price = $_POST['price'];
    echo  $qty= $_POST['qty'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into cart (productname,price,qty)values(?,?,?)");
    $stmt-> bind_param("sss",$productname,$price,$qty);
    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        echo 1;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: The only input on your form is `qty`. From here: `<input type='text' name='qty' id='qty'>`. You're not passing anything else to `addproduct.php`.

Comment: yes sir how to pass the values sir  div class='panel-heading' id='des' "  +  "<h4> "  +  description + "</h4> this  description  values

Comment: edited code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is not passing anything else other than `qty`. Elements like `<div>`, `<p>` and so on are not passed when the form is submitted. 
If you need to pass these values without showing them to the user in an actual input field, use `<input type="hidden" name="des" value="123">`, for example.

Comment: var price = data[i].price;
                        var image = data[i].image;
                        var description = data[i].description;      this how i am getting values then how to pass into <input type="hidden" name="des" value="123">

Comment: `"<input type='hidden' name='des' value='" + description + "'>"`

Comment: $stmt-> bind_param("sss",$productname,$price,$qty);  what is the problem on this line sir values are passing success

Comment: That would another question but my guess is that the `"sss"` is wrong. That argument passes the type of data. Your data seems to have one string and two numeric values. Check [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) out for more details.